# Distinct prime factorization function formulation to find mobius function?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, prime-factorization, mobius-function

### Background

I recently noticed the following:

$$ S(x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{p_r} $$

where $p_r$ is the $r$'th prime:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty S(x^r) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^{p_r}}{(1-x^{p_r})}  $$

However, we also notice that:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty S(x^r) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^{p_r}}{(1-x^{p_r})} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \omega(r) x^r  $$

Where $\omega(r)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $r$ and assigning $\omega(1)=0$ : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html
(More about it here)

Using the mobious inversion formula:

$$ S(x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{p_r} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \sum_{s=1}^\infty \mu(s) \omega(r) x^{rs}$$

We know

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{p_r} \sim \frac{1}{(x-1)\ln(1-x)}$$

as $x \nearrow 1$

### Questions

Is this correct?

Does this already exist? (If, so I will be more than happy for a reference)?

I was wondering if using this above information (including the link) can one say anything meaningful about $\mu(r)$ using this?

If not, what more information is required?

P.S: I have only taken one course in asymptotics in my physics degree (so basically I don't know much) ....

Comment: yes it is correct, and the coefficients of the Power series for $S(x)$ are the same as the RHS i.e. $\sum_{rs = n} \omega(s) \mu(r) = \sum_{d | n} \omega(n/d) \mu(d) = \delta_p(n)$ ($1$ if $n$ is prime, $0$ otherwise), this is true because $\omega(n) = \sum_{d|n} \delta_p(d)$

Comment: at least as formal power series, and it is true for $|x|<1$ because of their respective radius of convergence. and the first and highly non trivial property of $\mu(n)$ defined as the function such that $\sum_{d | n} \mu(n) = \delta(n)$ is that $\mu(n) =\pm 1$ or $0$ depending on $n$ is square-free or not.

Comment: and see for example http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371798 "On Riemann's Reduction of Dirichlet Series to Power series" to get more ideas

Comment: @user1952009 so people can say something useful about $\mu(r)$ using this and they already have done so? (Meanwhile I'm registering so I can read the stuff for free) ...

Comment: @user1952009 I also wanted to know if the expression for $S(x)$ was known?

Comment: I just wanted to show you the link between the Mellin transform of $\sum_n a_n e^{-nx}$ and $\Gamma(s) \sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ so that this kind of method can be applied to any Dirichlet series having a pole at $s=1$ to get an equivalent of $\sum_n a_n x^n$ when $x \to 1^{-}$ and that Riemann already new that